# Integral of exponential with $x(1-x)$ term

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Does the following integral have a closed form solution?

$$
\int_{0}^{y} \exp\left(\,-\sqrt{\,x(1-x)\,}\,\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

Or must I settle with an approximation?

---

Edit:
**Actual form of integral has an $\alpha$:**
$$
\int_{0}^{y} \exp\left(\, -\alpha \sqrt{\,x(1-x)\,}\,\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$
I need the solution (or approximate solution) work with large $\alpha$ (and if just possible for small $\alpha$ too

---

**2nd Edit: Is there analytic expression for the definite integral containing the $\alpha$?**
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \exp\left(\, -\alpha \sqrt{\,x(1-x)\,}\,\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

---

**3rd Edit: Actually it is $-\alpha$ not $\alpha$**

Comment: In terms of error and complementary error function yes. But in terms of a standard functions nope.

Comment: How I can find it in terms of error and complementary error function?

Comment: That was before the change in the equation I thought you had wrote $\left(\mathrm{e}^{f(x)}\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: One can argue the "error and complementary error function" aren't even "closed form" or "analytic", they are just symbols we assign something.  See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657885/could-a-computer-theoretically-compute-all-integrals-in-terms-of-some-special-fu/657890#657890)

Comment: @squirtle I eluded to that in my comment. But your very much right, I was kind of suggesting that was the best he could hope for :).

Comment: I am wondering that we have an analytical solution for exp(x^.5) why not exp((x*(1-x))^.5)

Comment: A pretty good approximation is given by $$\int_{0}^{y} \exp\left(\sqrt{x(1-x)}\right)\,dx \approx y (1.15964 + 0.990564y - 0.660376y^2)$$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you mention how close is this to numerical value (relative error)?

Comment: [Here's a plot of the relative error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SXxMa.png).  The maximum value is around $0.137666$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the plot.

Comment: Just a question, if there be a constant factor in the exponent like alpha, how the approximate solution would change.

Comment: @AntonioVargas It would be great if you can provide the solution with considering that constant alpha coefficient: epx(alpha * sqrt(x *(1-x) )).

Comment: I have decided to remove my answer below, because it bares no resemblance to the (many) revised question of the OP. Though I do think it deserves a place as a partial result as a comment.$$
\int_{0}^{-1}\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}= \frac{1}{2}\pi \left[L_{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + I_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\approx 1.48983
$$
has a solution
[modified Struve function $L_{-1}(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).
The answer is approximately 1.48983 which corresponds to previous comment above by @AntonioVargas.

Comment: @Hesam, I don't think I can get the same type of approximation with $\alpha$ there, and I also think it's unlikely that there will be a single approximation that is good for both $\alpha$ small and $\alpha$ large.  Would different approximations in each of these cases be sufficient?

Comment: @Hesam, Also, is it alright if the approximation includes the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), or are you looking for something more closed-form?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Even if it works for large alpha, it works for me. The simpler the solution, better.

Comment: @Chinny84 Is there analytic solution for integration from 0 to 1, if we have the alpha constant coefficient in the exponent?

Comment: Most likely. I predict you can take the solution I provide in a comment above..and replace $1/2$ by $\alpha / 2$. Try it out and report back. :)

Comment: Also, Use the solution (it's a real goodun) of Claude below.

Comment: @Chinny84 You predict correctly. This can be shown using the substitution $u=2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ and comparing the power series.

Comment: @Chinny84 Actually I think it is not right! I did the numerical calculations and these are values for $\alpha$ = 1,2,3 Val = 1.4898, 2.2440, 3.4120

Comment: @Hesam What's not right? Are referring to chinny's value in terms of the Struve and Bessel functions? It gives the correct numerical values...

Comment: No I meant when we consider $\alpha$ in the exponential and if we multiply the previous results with $\alpha$, they are not same. I mean the point you verified is wrong, but one point which 1/2 should be replaced?

Comment: @Hesam Ok, I think I see what your mistake was. It seems like you replaced the wrong "1/2" by $\alpha/2$. Here's a color coded version of the identity when $\alpha=1$: $\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}\pi \left[L_{-1}\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\right) + I_{1}\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right]$. To generalize the formula to any $alpha$, replace only the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ 1/2's by $\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: @Hesam I.e., the general formula should read: $\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{e}^{\color{red}{\alpha}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}\pi \left[L_{-1}\left(\color{red}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right) + I_{1}\left(\color{red}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)\right]$.

Comment: @DavidH Do you know the functions $L_{-1}$ and $I_{1}$ and how to call them through Matlab?

Comment: @hesam $L$ is the modified Struve function, and $I$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. See definitions here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedStruveFunction.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html . I'm not familiar with matlab, but it shouldn't be too hard to look up the implementations.

Comment: @DavidH Cheers for improving my solution :). So thank you.

Comment: hasem at first I was taken in by a beautiful question, but now it is ridiculous. You have made a numerous set of revisions. So the solutions provided during the process of this question are sufficient for you to answer your question. Just do a bit of research and try to modify the solution that me and @davidh have helped with or indeed Claude's answer.  But here is something for free with regards to my previous answer which seems applicable once again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^y e^{-\alpha\sqrt{x(1-x)}}~dx$

$=\int_0^y e^{-\alpha\sqrt{-(x^2-x)}}~dx$

$=\int_0^y e^{-\alpha\sqrt{-\left(x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}}~dx$

$=\int_0^y e^{-\alpha\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}~dx$

$=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{y-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\alpha\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}}~dx$

$=\int_\pi^{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}e^{-\alpha\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{\cos x}{2}\right)^2}}~d\left(\dfrac{\cos x}{2}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi e^{-\frac{\alpha\sin x}{2}}\sin x~dx$

$=\int_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\alpha^{2n}\sin^{2n+1}x}{2^{2n+1}(2n)!}dx-\int_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\alpha^{2n+1}\sin^{2n+2}x}{4^{n+1}(2n+1)!}dx$

For $n$ is any non-negative integer,

$\int\sin^{2n+2}x~dx=\dfrac{(2n+2)!x}{4^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(2n+2)!(k!)^2\sin^{2k+1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}((n+1)!)^2(2k+1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

$\int\sin^{2n+1}x~dx$

$=-\int\sin^{2n}x~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int(1-\cos^2x)^n~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^nC_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}x~d(\cos x)$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}n!\cos^{2k+1}x}{k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$\therefore\int_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\alpha^{2n}\sin^{2n+1}x}{2^{2n+1}(2n)!}dx-\int_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\alpha^{2n+1}\sin^{2n+2}x}{4^{n+1}(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}n!\alpha^{2n}\cos^{2k+1}x}{2^{2n+1}(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}\right]_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi-\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\alpha^{2n+1}x}{2^{4n+3}n!(n+1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(k!)^2\alpha^{2n+1}\sin^{2k+1}x\cos x}{2^{4n-2k+3}n!(n+1)!(2k+1)!}\right]_{\cos^{-1}(2y-1)}^\pi$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\alpha^{2n}((2y-1)^{2k+1}+1)}{2^{2n+1}(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\alpha^{2n+1}(\cos^{-1}(2y-1)-\pi)}{2^{4n+3}n!(n+1)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(k!)^2\alpha^{2n+1}(2y-1)(1-(2y-1)^2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}}{2^{4n-2k+3}n!(n+1)!(2k+1)!}$

Comment: Many thanks, does the solution have a short form based on the functions we know?

Comment: I have asked that here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907243/short-form-of-few-series/907313#907313

Answer (score 7):

$\textbf{Possible direction}$

$$
\sqrt{x(1-x)} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}.
$$
thus making a change of variable 
$$
\cos(t) = 2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right),\\
-\sin(t)dt = 2dx.
$$
we can re-write the integral as
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi}^{0} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin(t)}\sin(t)dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin(t)}\sin(t)dt
$$

so the original integral looks like
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin(s)}\sin(s)ds = \frac{1}{2}\pi \left[L_{-1}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + I_{1}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right]\approx 1.48983
$$
$\textbf{update:}$
There seems to be a discrepancy between this "answer"  and the numerical result obtained in the comments above. If you could please refrain from voting until the differences are accounted for that will be great. Cheers!

$\textbf{update 2}$
The last equation has been modified from my previous answer due to my silly mistake of converting the limits of the integration! Anyway, using mathematica (apologies) the final integral is of the form [modified Struve function $L_{-1}(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).
The answer is approximately 1.48983 for $\alpha =1$ and limits 0 to 1, which corresponds to previous comment above.

$\textbf{update 3}$
Modified answer as mentioned in the comments to the original question. Now try to find a way to represent the special functions with negative arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how I can change the integration (from x=0 to x=y) instead of (from x=0 to x=1)?

Comment: Unfortunately I make use of the identity Eq(**) which (I have not tried to prove this one way or the other) works for 0 to $2\pi$. Maybe wait for a more complete answer or I can try to modify in the morning :).

Comment: The value of integral from 0 to 1 seems to be 1.5 (numerical integration value). But I can not get that value from your solution. Is it right?

Comment: How have you dealt with the negative argument in the modified Bessel function? I will have a further look at the numerical values compared with the "answer" above in the morning.

Comment: Basically everything after the change of variables checks out. But when comparing the numerical integration of your integral and the integral with the change of variables there is a divergence :/. I might just delete this answer until I can rectify..though I feel that my morning brain or even better some of the whizzs on here can see my errors.

Comment: Just in the last step where you are derivating with respect to $\alpha$, shouldn't $dL_0/d\alpha = L_{-1} + L_1 + ...$

Comment: But I am taking the derivative of $I_0$ not the Struve function. :/

Comment: Isn't it $L_0 + I_0$ before taking derivative wrt $\alpha$?

Comment: Nope. But I could be wrong. Put it through wolfram the integral before and see what we get? Update accordingly

Comment: That is what I did :) and was wondering where is the difference.

Answer (score 5):

For the range $0 \leq y \leq 1$, you may have a very accurate estimation of the integral expanding first the integrand as a Taylor series built at $x=0$. This gives 
$$e^{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=1+\sqrt{x}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{11 x^2}{24}-\frac{11
   x^{5/2}}{30}-\frac{59 x^3}{720}-\frac{13 x^{7/2}}{630}+\frac{1513
   x^4}{40320}-\frac{311 x^{9/2}}{22680}+\frac{14761 x^5}{3628800}-\frac{31417
   x^{11/2}}{1247400}-\frac{594659 x^6}{479001600}-\frac{1877123
   x^{13/2}}{97297200}-\frac{8409491 x^7}{87178291200}+O\left(x^{15/2}\right)$$ Then, for the integral, you have $$\int_{0}^{y} e^{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,{\rm d}x=y+\frac{2 y^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{y^2}{4}-\frac{2 y^{5/2}}{15}-\frac{11 y^3}{72}-\frac{11
   y^{7/2}}{105}-\frac{59 y^4}{2880}-\frac{13 y^{9/2}}{2835}+\frac{1513
   y^5}{201600}-\frac{311 y^{11/2}}{124740}+\frac{14761 y^6}{21772800}-\frac{31417
   y^{13/2}}{8108100}-\frac{594659 y^7}{3353011200}-\frac{1877123
   y^{15/2}}{729729000}-\frac{8409491 y^8}{697426329600}+O\left(y^{17/2}\right)$$ which is quite accurate.

**Added later after OP's request**

If we consider the case of $$\int_{0}^{y} e^{a\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,{\rm d}x$$ assuming that $a$ is small, an identical procedure first leads to $$e^{a\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=1+a \sqrt{x}+\frac{a^2 x}{2}+\frac{1}{6} a \left(a^2-3\right) x^{3/2}+\frac{1}{24}
   a^2 \left(a^2-12\right) x^2+\frac{1}{120} a \left(a^4-30 a^2-15\right)
   x^{5/2}+\frac{1}{720} a^4 \left(a^2-60\right) x^3+\frac{a \left(a^6-105 a^4+315
   a^2-315\right) x^{7/2}}{5040}+\frac{a^4 \left(a^4-168 a^2+1680\right)
   x^4}{40320}+\frac{a \left(a^8-252 a^6+5670 a^4+3780 a^2-14175\right)
   x^{9/2}}{362880}+\frac{a^6 \left(a^4-360 a^2+15120\right) x^5}{3628800}+\frac{a
   \left(a^{10}-495 a^8+34650 a^6-103950 a^4+155925 a^2-1091475\right)
   x^{11/2}}{39916800}+\frac{a^6 \left(a^6-660 a^4+71280 a^2-665280\right)
   x^6}{479001600}+\frac{a \left(a^{12}-858 a^{10}+135135 a^8-2702700 a^6-2027025
   a^4+12162150 a^2-127702575\right) x^{13/2}}{6227020800}+\frac{a^8 \left(a^6-1092
   a^4+240240 a^2-8648640\right) x^7}{87178291200}+O\left(x^{15/2}\right)$$ and, then, for the integral
$$\int_{0}^{y} e^{a\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,{\rm d}x=y+\frac{2}{3} a y^{3/2}+\frac{a^2 y^2}{4}+\frac{1}{15} a \left(a^2-3\right)
   y^{5/2}+\frac{1}{72} a^2 \left(a^2-12\right) y^3+\frac{1}{420} a \left(a^4-30
   a^2-15\right) y^{7/2}+\frac{a^4 \left(a^2-60\right) y^4}{2880}+\frac{a
   \left(a^6-105 a^4+315 a^2-315\right) y^{9/2}}{22680}+\frac{a^4 \left(a^4-168
   a^2+1680\right) y^5}{201600}+\frac{a \left(a^8-252 a^6+5670 a^4+3780
   a^2-14175\right) y^{11/2}}{1995840}+\frac{a^6 \left(a^4-360 a^2+15120\right)
   y^6}{21772800}+\frac{a \left(a^{10}-495 a^8+34650 a^6-103950 a^4+155925
   a^2-1091475\right) y^{13/2}}{259459200}+\frac{a^6 \left(a^6-660 a^4+71280
   a^2-665280\right) y^7}{3353011200}+\frac{a \left(a^{12}-858 a^{10}+135135
   a^8-2702700 a^6-2027025 a^4+12162150 a^2-127702575\right)
   y^{15/2}}{46702656000}+\frac{a^8 \left(a^6-1092 a^4+240240 a^2-8648640\right)
   y^8}{697426329600}+O\left(y^{17/2}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, Could you mention what if we have a constant coefficient alpha in the exponent: exp(alpha * (x*(1-x))^.5)

Comment: I shall update my answer right now.

Comment: Sure, I am waiting to see if someone can provide analytic short form solution.

Comment: I tried your solution with small a and result macthes very good. However for large a the result is wrong. Do you think it is possible to make it work for large a with some trick.

Comment: It is normal that large $a$'s will cause problems. Let me think about it.

Comment: Given the OP's change of heart with the question, This is the far superior answer! +1

Comment: @Chinny84. Thank you ! I really appreciate this comment from you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I'm not able to write good mathematical content on this site yet, I've just signed up.

I think it is possible to find an analytical solution to this.
First the function : $x --> x*(1-x)$ is bijective when x is between 0 and $\frac{1}{2}$. So we can assume that x verifies that, or we seperate the integral in two, one part from 0 to $\frac{1}{2}$ and the other from $\frac{1}{2}$ to y knowing that the method to calculate it is the same.

First we change variables with $u^2 = x*(1-x)$ that gives $x= (1-\frac{\sqrt{1-4*u^2}}{2})$ (two solutions but only one of them is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$))

replace it in the integral and use an integration by parts on $4*\frac{u}{\sqrt{(1-4*u^2)}}$ that should show up after the correct re-writing of the integral following the change of variable.

Then to simplify notation, use another one : $v=2*u$ ( we could do it before the integration by part)

If I'm right you should obtain a certain function of y (the main variable) which is made of roots and exponentials so is known) and $\int \sqrt{(1-v^2)}*e^{\frac{v}{2}}$ delimited by the proper values ( here 0 and $\frac{1}{2}*\sqrt{y(1-y)}$ ).
Then you use a sin change of variable : v=sin(t) and it gives you :

the same term function of y, and $\int cos(t)^2*e^{\frac{sin(t)}{2}}$
From here, you use two integration by parts to sort the thing out and it should give you the analytical solution, ugly as it is :) . 
I may have been mistaken at some point so please don't hesitate to tell me if it turns out to be so. 
Thank you to those who read this to the end :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You'll want to read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/137524) on Mathjax so that you can make your mathematics as accessible and clear as possible. In the same vein, I'd suggest you convert as much of your words into specific mathematical content (integrals, changes of variables, etc.) That'll make it much easier for everyone to assess your argument.